# Prolog first integer exactly 1 greater than second integer

Tags: prolog, successor-arithmetics

The program should return true if the first integer is exactly 1 more than the second integer.

Current code returns false every time.

Without the line abs(X-Y) == 1 it's working for checking if the second integer is more than the first, but it should check if the difference is exactly 1.

```
expected output:

greater_than(succ(succ(0)),succ(0)).
yes
greater_than(succ(succ(0)),succ(succ(succ(0))))) 
no

current code :
greater_than(succ(X),0).
greater_than(succ(X),succ(Y)) :-
   abs(X-Y) == 1,
   greater_than(X,Y).
```

Comment: First of all, Prolog is not going to evaluate the `X-Y` in the abs call unless you use the `=:=` operator. Second, if you're trying to implement Peano arithmetic, there is definitely no way Prolog's built-in arithmetic operators are going to understand that, so you will have to find another way to implement this. Think about what `Y = succ(X)` would tell you about X and Y if Y was representing some number, such as 3 or 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *Peano* number *x* is exactly one greater than a Peano number *y*, given *x = succ(y)*, so we can here write this like:

```
one_greater_than(succ(X), X).
```

Given the first argument thus is of shape `succ(X)`, Prolog will aim to *unify* the only argument of the `succ/1` functor with the second predicate.